# java, mysql and apache package for ms-windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, java, apache-http-server, mysql

from where i can get package which includes java, mysql and apache for windows xp?
how we can install a package of java, mysql and apache on ms-windows xp on single click?

Answer (score 1):

No such package exists to my knowledge. You'd have to whip something up yourself if you want this. Java isn't as popular as PHP in packages like this.

I think the NetBeans IDE bundles Apache Tomcat and Java, but it is not single-click and does not contain MySQL.

My suggestion would be to download all 3 installers and see how they are packaged. Most installers have a switch for silent installation such as `/q` which can aid you in writing a small batch script to install all 3 at once. You may want to check out [App Deploy](http://appdeploy.com) for some hints.

For Java runtime, e.g.:

```
jre-6u22-windows-i586-s.exe /s /v /qn ADDLOCAL=ALL IEXPLORER=1 JAVAUPDATE=0
```

My only concern with 1-click installers is the cruft it is putting on your machine in the background. I like selectively picking what options I want in the installer, while a 1-click mechanism takes away those options (so what is it selecting in the background?!?!).

Answer (score 1):

I think [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is the closest thing available -

> XAMPP is an easy to install Apache
> distribution containing MySQL, PHP and
> Perl. XAMPP is really very easy to
> install and to use - just download,
> extract and start.

In my experience, it installs very quickly, and every component functions/integrates correctly.